# Does HeapCreate return the heap handle into EAX?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, heap-memory, masm

I am using the masm assembler, and I am using the kernel32.lib to create heap memory, however on the windows API page for the HeapCreate procedure it does not tell me where it's return value is stored. (i.e. the handle to the heap)
I would assume that it is stored in `EAX`? since most procedures place their return value in `EAX`. After I call HeapCreate, I call HealAlloc to allocate some memory in my heap:

```
INCLUDE \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
INCLUDELIB \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
.CODE

PUSH DWORD PTR 00h ;max size
PUSH DWORD PTR 00h ;initial size
PUSH DWORD PTR 04h ;flOption
CALL HeapCreate

PUSH DWORD PTR 04h ;dwBytes (the size in bytes)
PUSH DWORD PTR 04h ;dwFlag
PUSH EAX ;I am not sure if the heap handle is stored in EAX or not?
CALL HeapAlloc

END
```

Essentially, I do not know where the return value to `HeapCreate` is stored. If anyone could clarify where, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the stdcall calling convention, which is the default used for Windows API calls. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MSDN page for HeapCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599.aspx) gives the following prototype for the function:

```
HANDLE WINAPI HeapCreate(
  _In_ DWORD  flOptions,
  _In_ SIZE_T dwInitialSize,
  _In_ SIZE_T dwMaximumSize
);
```

All x86 calling conventions leave the return value in `R/EAX`, so the resulting `HANDLE` will be found in either `EAX` (in 32-bit builds) or `RAX` (in 64-bit builds).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you are compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit.

The declaration of `HeapCreate()` is as follows:

```
HANDLE WINAPI HeapCreate(
  _In_ DWORD  flOptions,
  _In_ SIZE_T dwInitialSize,
  _In_ SIZE_T dwMaximumSize
);
```

`WINAPI` is a preprocessor macro that resolves to the `__stdcall` calling convention, which is meaningful only in 32-bit and is ignored in 64-bit.

In 32-bit, `__stdcall` stores return values up to 32 bits in `EAX`, and larger return values in `EAX:EDX`.

In 64-bit, the x64 calling convention stores return values in `RAX` (the first 32 bits of which are `EAX`).

`HANDLE` is a pointer type, so it is 32 bits in size on a 32-bit compilation, and 64 bits in size on a 64-bit compilation.  However, [MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203.aspx):

> **64-bit versions of Windows use 32-bit handles for interoperability**. When sharing a handle between 32-bit and 64-bit applications, only the lower 32 bits are significant, so it is safe to truncate the handle (when passing it from 64-bit to 32-bit) or sign-extend the handle (when passing it from 32-bit to 64-bit). Handles that can be shared include handles to user objects such as windows (`HWND`), handles to GDI objects such as pens and brushes (`HBRUSH` and `HPEN`), and handles to named objects such as mutexes, semaphores, and file handles.

Because of this, using `EAX` alone *may* be valid for `HANDLE` values returned by `HeapCreate()` in both 32-bit and 64-bit compilations.  However, the `HANDLE` returned by `HeapCreate()` is not generally shared across process boundaries, so it *may* take up more than 32 bits.

Best not to take chances one way or the other.  Use `EAX` in 32-bit, and `RAX` in 64-bit, since that is what the respective calling conventions dictate.